# My macbook pro 2014 screen is flickering and shuts it self

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, macos

I am not sure but it might happened after the High Sierra update.  What i have done to resolve the issue is

1. reset the SMC
2. reset the NVRAM
3. I have upgraded to Mojave
4. i have erased the disk and reinstalled the OSX

None of them provided permanent solutions.

Now the OSX is 10.13.6 after the reinstall and revert from time machine.

> I have tried on safe mode. Although, the symptomes are different, the
>   screen is still flickering and going black.

```
On the external screen, there is no problem.
```

> The issue doesn't occur while i am watching a video (on Youtube, Netflix).

Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: I’m not sure if you are experiencing system shutdowns when the screen goes black, but if so it sounds similar to [this random shutdown issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290714/macbook-pro-black-screens-and-shuts-off-after-a-few-minutes-use).

Comment: No, just the screen goes off.