# Catalina crashing at shutdown: "watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd"

Tags: macos, crash, shutdown, catalina

I have an iMac late 2012 with 24GB or RAM and 3 USB disks connected to it, all running time machine in sequence.

After updating to catalina, every time I shutdown the system it takes ages to shutdown and then after reaching the shutdown state, sometimes the screen turns white again, as if it would start again and after a while the screen turns black again with a shutdown message at the middle, in several languages.

Then, if I start the system, I see this crash message:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7fa6c96aae): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 184 seconds (97 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff82e0b13c40 : 0xffffff802553f98b 
0xffffff82e0b13c90 : 0xffffff8025676c15 
0xffffff82e0b13cd0 : 0xffffff802566861e 
0xffffff82e0b13d20 : 0xffffff80254e6a40 
0xffffff82e0b13d40 : 0xffffff802553f077 
0xffffff82e0b13e40 : 0xffffff802553f45b 
0xffffff82e0b13e90 : 0xffffff8025cd2e05 
0xffffff82e0b13f00 : 0xffffff7fa6c96aae 
0xffffff82e0b13f10 : 0xffffff7fa6c96472 
0xffffff82e0b13f50 : 0xffffff7fa6cabfd6 
0xffffff82e0b13fa0 : 0xffffff80254e613e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[58392D62-D9E8-3022-85C1-B78AC93B9167]@0xffffff7fa6c95000->0xffffff7fa6c9dfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[EB9D605D-85B1-3506-8B2E-ABD195817A4F]@0xffffff7fa6c9e000->0xffffff7fa6cbcfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[9BA2613C-A129-3EDD-8DC1-2CFF6B62B832]@0xffffff7fa6c8c000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[58392D62-D9E8-3022-85C1-B78AC93B9167]@0xffffff7fa6c95000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E6E855AD-A5B2-3518-A997-1384B4360708]@0xffffff7fa5f2f000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19A583

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Wed Sep 25 20:18:50 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.11.26~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 70EDD61F-8D909B78160
Kernel slide:     0x0000000025200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8025400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8025300000
System model name: iMac13,2 (Mac-FC02E91DDD3FA6A4)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002cd)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1201012930700
last loaded kext at 692174279981: @filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7fa9e1c000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 67316368087: >!AXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7fa89a7000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
>!A!BMultitouch 97
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.1.46
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.1.46
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.0f8
>AGPM   111.1.18
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.14
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@GeForce    14.0.0
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.1.46
>!AHDA  283.14
>eficheck   1
>!AMikeyDriver  283.14
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!ABacklight    170.18
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.0
@nvidia.NVDAStartup 14.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.12
@fileutil   20.036.15
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.11.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    302
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.0f8
>!AMultitouchDriver 3400.35
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3400.27
>!AGraphicsControl  4.1.46
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal 14.0.0
@nvidia.driver.NVDAResman   14.0.0
>DspFuncLib 283.14
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.1.46
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  558.3
>!AHDA!C    283.14
|IOHDA!F    283.14
|IOAudio!F  300.2
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.1.23
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.1.46
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   558.3
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
@kext.triggers  1.0
>Core!S 551
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.0f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.0f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.0f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.0f8
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOSerial!F 11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOSurface  269.6
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.5.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.5
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.0.5
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.11.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.11.2
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

It calls my attention this line `@filesystems.msdosfs`... MS DOS FILE SYSTEM???? WTF!

My ideas were to reset the SMC and try a safe boot. Neither addressed the issue, it persists.

What next steps might help me avoid the crash?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can temporarily make things better by looking for this line:

```
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[EB9D605D-85B1-3506-8B2E-ABD195817A4F]@0xffffff7fa6c9e000->0xffffff7fa6cbcfff
```

My theory is SMC is sometimes slow or stuck. Here's the temporary workaround:

1. Start shutdown procedure normally, it will take about 3 minutes until it crashes and reboots
2. After it reboots, don't log in - press the shutdown button (on the bottom of screen) instead. This time, it will shutdown normally.
3. Do the SMC reset procedure described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) by Apple

So far, I've tested this (and it worked) on my 2019 MacBook Pro and my friend's 2015 MacBook Pro. It doesn’t cure the gap, but the reset brings stability for a while. If this is intermittent, consider it a warning your hardware is aging and needs a repair / Apple detailed diagnostics and not just the built in hardware test that ships with each Mac.

Answer (score 8):

I finally solved this issue on my M1 and Intel Macs.

It was caused by certain apps installed with home-brew, and interaction with the kernel.

Details [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412584/m1-mac-kernel-panic-on-reboot-no-checkins-from-watchdogd).

TLDR: Running `gem` installed by `brew` causes a KP on reboot.

I removed Ruby from my Path, and removed it from `powerlevel10k`.
Immediately resolved the issue.

Why is `gem` causing this?

**Update:**
I can consistently reproduce it using a number of ways using various apps, and it's weird. All of these apps are installed via home-brew -

- Using ruby and then gem installed via home-brew, i.e. executing /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby, then /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/gem, then rebooting - see KP.
- Executing "thef*ck" (https://github.com/nvbn/thef*ck) - see KP.
- Executing "pip3 list" installed via homebrew, i.e. "/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3 list" - see KP.

**UPDATE2 - SOLUTION**
My replication steps only work when my terminal emulator (iTerm/Terminal) was in added in "Developer Tools" section of Security & Privacy settings in macOS.

Removed them and I could not longer replicate.

This looks to be a bug in codesign/watchdogd/adhoc signatures. Where you remove the terminal from dev tools, you can see the signature check is performed and all is well.

If you have terminal in the "developer tools" category, certain tools (like the ones I describe in my post, ruby/pip), cause the OS to panic on reboot, as something ends up hanging.

Described further here: https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/

Answer (score 6):

I also had this kernel panic on two identical devices running 10.15.5 and it drove me mad.

So I just did a couple of hours of trial and error and kextload und kextunload, plugging and unplugging and about three dozen reboots and I got this thing reproducable. Kicker is this:
At least in my case it is only triggered when

a) an external display is connected via USBc->HDMI

b) the MBP is in clamshell mode

None of the kexts had any influence surprisingly. It will not panic in any other combination (i.e. an external display is connected but the lid is not shut).

It looks to me like the unload of >usb.!UHostPacketFilter triggers the crash because it is the only display but it must not be running when no display is connected and the lid is closed.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa1c04b81): "[IGPU] sendHostToGucMessage: Firmware communication error: no action response!\n"@icl/sched3/IGGuC.cpp:3599
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3f0b8b350 : 0xffffff801d9215cd 
0xffffffa3f0b8b3a0 : 0xffffff801da5a405 
0xffffffa3f0b8b3e0 : 0xffffff801da4bf8e 
0xffffffa3f0b8b430 : 0xffffff801d8c7a40 
0xffffffa3f0b8b450 : 0xffffff801d920c97 
0xffffffa3f0b8b550 : 0xffffff801d921087 
0xffffffa3f0b8b5a0 : 0xffffff801e0c2d8c 
0xffffffa3f0b8b610 : 0xffffff7fa1c04b81 
0xffffffa3f0b8b650 : 0xffffff7fa1b8e521 
0xffffffa3f0b8b680 : 0xffffff7fa1b8c7b9 
0xffffffa3f0b8b6b0 : 0xffffff7fa1b8ec14 
0xffffffa3f0b8b710 : 0xffffff7fa1b8f793 
0xffffffa3f0b8b750 : 0xffffff7fa1c04b1c 
0xffffffa3f0b8b790 : 0xffffff7fa1b8e521 
0xffffffa3f0b8b7c0 : 0xffffff7fa1b8c826 
0xffffffa3f0b8b7f0 : 0xffffff7fa1b8eba4 
0xffffffa3f0b8b850 : 0xffffff7fa1b99d20 
0xffffffa3f0b8b870 : 0xffffff7fa157f88c 
0xffffffa3f0b8b8b0 : 0xffffff7fa15c56fd 
0xffffffa3f0b8b8f0 : 0xffffff7fa1516d68 
0xffffffa3f0b8ba30 : 0xffffff7fa1501e16 
0xffffffa3f0b8bac0 : 0xffffff7fa150940f 
0xffffffa3f0b8bb60 : 0xffffff801e0021df 
0xffffffa3f0b8bbd0 : 0xffffff801e09630f 
0xffffffa3f0b8bc30 : 0xffffff801e0029c9 
0xffffffa3f0b8bc80 : 0xffffff801e0958c9 
0xffffffa3f0b8bd40 : 0xffffff801de82866 
0xffffffa3f0b8be00 : 0xffffff801de9cf19 
0xffffffa3f0b8bf40 : 0xffffff801df87707 
0xffffffa3f0b8bfa0 : 0xffffff801d8c8206 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[2EDEB7A5-F163-3BBA-B3EE-E508E6A1A920]@0xffffff7fa14f8000->0xffffff7fa1548fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[6F96761B-C218-30A8-BECC-1EAD32E53D47]@0xffffff7f9e311000
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.4.5)[108DA6E8-6995-3986-9CA9-B73150768244]@0xffffff7fa157e000->0xffffff7fa1641fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[64DD6A97-6E35-3BF4-AA75-46EFC42F574B]@0xffffff7f9ea2e000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[6F96761B-C218-30A8-BECC-1EAD32E53D47]@0xffffff7f9e311000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[EE3C1ABC-E424-3EBE-B1D6-913048CE7EA1]@0xffffff7f9fe78000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[2EDEB7A5-F163-3BBA-B3EE-E508E6A1A920]@0xffffff7fa14f8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[28F06131-E9AB-3980-9175-6B4EAB4326EE]@0xffffff7f9e249000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelICLGraphics(14.0.5)[A2D58B1A-D6F2-3A51-B159-9AED33F36FC1]@0xffffff7fa1b76000->0xffffff7fa1cb3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[6F96761B-C218-30A8-BECC-1EAD32E53D47]@0xffffff7f9e311000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[EE3C1ABC-E424-3EBE-B1D6-913048CE7EA1]@0xffffff7f9fe78000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(575.1)[2EDEB7A5-F163-3BBA-B3EE-E508E6A1A920]@0xffffff7fa14f8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.4.5)[108DA6E8-6995-3986-9CA9-B73150768244]@0xffffff7fa157e000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: launchd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19E2269

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:47:48 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~16/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7559A1A8-B300-3BC5-900F-5ED91F3197C7
Kernel slide:     0x000000001d600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801d800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801d700000
System model name: MacBookPro16,2 (Mac-5F9802EFE386AA28)
System shutdown begun: YES

System uptime in nanoseconds: 21814331773601
last loaded kext at 115722074408: @filesystems.smbfs    3.4.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa1d79000, size 450560)
last unloaded kext at 196519170346: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa01e4000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
jp.co.yamaha.driver.YamahaSteinbergUSBAudio 2.0.3
net.sf.tuntaposx.tap    1.0
net.sf.tuntaposx.tun    1.0
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4.2
>!A!BMultitouch 97
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IICLGraphics    14.0.5
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!IICLLPGraphicsFramebuffer   14.0.5
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
|IOAVB!F    840.3
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!UAudio    322.2
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: Still happening on 3 Macs I own including an M1 based Mac: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/m1-issues-post-them-all-here.2271533/post-29345397

Comment: @Woodstock I was hoping they'd fix it on Big Sur but I cannot upgrade yet due to compatibility issues. Are your machines on Big Sur already? I talked to Business Support, they said they'd never heard of this problem

Comment: nope still on Big Sur, even on an M1 ARM, Apple Silicon Mac. I wrote a letter to Cook and had my near 7 month old 16inch maxed pro refunded over this. I wrote to Mac engineering, macOS dev, spoke to 2xcustomer liaison, executive team, 4xsenior advisor and 3 agents, it's preposterous.

Comment: @Woodstock How massively annoying. I currently only have my production device, otherwise I'd try to wipe it completely and do a fresh install of the base system to see if it still happens. Have you tried that already?

Comment: Yep, tried that about 6 times. Tried all sorts, beta profiles of big sur, running with no apps, I even identified likely the kernel code causing the issue in XNU and provided a diagnostic to engineering. - it will be fixed eventually. This occurs on 3 machines I have, even after clean install.

Comment: @Woodstock Thanks for working so hard on this. You've also saved me some time. I have reported it like a dozen times also to all sorts of people but everyone so far usually tells me it's just my machine which is obviously just trying to not comment on it and shift blame. Let's hope someone fells the need to fix it. I'm also surprised this is not a bigger deal publicly. Is noone using their Notebooks in clamshell?

Comment: 16" MBP user here, nearly always run in clamshell mode at home, and when in clamshell always connected to a Caldigit TS3+ dock with a DP display and several USB doo-dads always plugged in. Have yet to experience this. macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: @CraigStodolenak maybe it has something to do with what kind of display or how it is attached... I use a cheap old Samsung display. It wouldn't be an absolute first if there was some newer display hardware or compatibility chips or certified cable they require. What do you think? I'm using some Amazon usb3->Hdmi cable to a 12 year old 100€ 22" Samsung Display

Answer (score 4):

After SMC and NVRAM reset I still get:

panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f891f9a8d): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 96 seconds (17427 total checkins since monitoring last enabled)

I'm working with an Apple senior advisor on this.  Apple is aware of the problem, but apparently has found no common cause.

In my case virtual box is something I suspect injecting instability.

Comment: I also have such issue with virtualbox installed

Answer (score 3):

My computer was also failing to shut down or reboot properly from being logged in with essentially the same crash message. The issue started happening after updating to 10.15.1. After resetting the SMC and also NVRAM the issue seems to have gone away.

Comment: Is it still OK?  It went away on the first reboot for me after NVRAM reset (probably because that deletes the kernel panic log), but then it came back.

Comment: @rayjosborne Did the SMC reset fix "hold" for you? Or did the problem return? Because I'm having this shutdown crash too (on multiple Macs) but I've done the SMC reset and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: @luckman212 I can't remember to be honest. I think it must have. It may have happened again straight after, but if so I presume I used the same fix and it went away again and I haven't had the issue ever since. I am now running 10.15.5 in any case, so maybe try updating to the latest version of MacOS

Answer (score 3):

So my MBP 16'' would sometimes simply shut down in the middle of the bootup process, and when I looked at the logs, it also reported kernel panic with `com.apple.driver.watchdog`. I tried every fix possible, disabled startup items and kernel extensions etc. to no avail. I was able to start it in the safe mode, but it would still behave strangely and be very sluggish even there.

I thus began to suspect that it was simply an issue of actual **overheating**. I put my MBP 16'' in the freezer for a while, and also kept it there during the bootup, and it actually worked! It booted up correctly and never reported any kernel panic or shut itself down.

Apparently the current heat wave (~36 degrees Celsius) was too much for the chassis to handle. Who would have thought that you'd need to resort such a primitive workaround on a $3000 device...

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Google File Stream?
I had exactly the same problem as yours and [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390620/macos-catalina-watchdog-timeout-kernel-panics) worked for my case: Excluding root folder of Google File Stream from spotlight. [image]

[edited] The frequency of watchdog timeout crash decreased, not went away. It still occurs about once a week.

Answer (score 2):

See most recent edit below.

<s>For anyone still dealing with this: what finally worked for me was installing the combo update [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL2048?locale=en_US). I'm able to reboot/shutdown without the stall. If that changes I'll edit this answer.</s>

This is a frustrating kernel bug that is directly due to the Catalina update (I was on El Capitan before this). The issue is still actively discussed on apple forums. I tried pretty much everything here (resetting NVRAM, resetting PRAM, removing 32 bit apps, and removing all 3rd party Kexts) with no success there. I also don't use external monitors.

If the combo update doesn't work then I would suggest next backing up and doing a full reinstall of macOS. Otherwise call up apple and complain that their update broke your machine. For what it's worth I'm on a macbook pro from 2015.

Good luck.

EDIT: After a few weeks, the problem returned. It continues on most (but not all) shutdowns/restarts. I still haven't changed my OS version since my original answer was made.

**EDIT 2 (some time later):**

I have now been without this problem for many months and therefore feel more confident in sharing what I believe fixed it. It was not from an update by Apple; I re-partitioned the main SSD to dual-boot my pro, and then scrapped the project when I found out the OS I wanted didn't support any drivers for my wifi card. So I re-partitioned it a second time, to remove the partition I created. Since then I can't recall having any kernel panics. I would only recommend trying this as a shot in the dark and definitely **back up your data before doing so**. Good luck and please if you follow this advice let us know if it succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 1):

I can't yet remove all 32-bit apps, but I have noticed that my second monitor, an old Samsung was going purple from time to time. Had to switch it of then on again to get it to work.

I read that second monitors can cause the watchdog timeout as well, so I turned off my second monitor and unplugged it. The Watchdog problem seems to have gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Catalina but didn't restore the TimeMachine backup. After Catalina was installed I created my user session and restored my personal files with iCloud (200GB subscription); the lager files were copied from the TimeMachine using Finder.

Now I can leave the iMac in suspend mode all the day waking up it several times and no BSD.

Answer (score -1):

Removing all 32bit apps and upgrading to 10.15.3 worked for me.

Comment: It's not clear that this is really an answer to the question, please consider removing this and posting it as a comment on the original question.