# MBP - Catalina 15.1. - recurring Kernel Panic

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, kernel-panic

I am at a loss of solutions for this problem. I keep getting these kernel panics with random reboots at the most unpleasant times.

Things tried:

- formatted and reinstalled MacOS Catalina 15.1. thrice
- SMC / NVRAM reset
- file-system check on errors
- not installing any additional software after clean re-install
- Safe-boot

Nothing of this helped. I am still having these problems.

Any help for this? I would greatly appreciate any points for new directions.

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0b
 family: 6 model: 142 stepping: 10 microcode: 180
 signature: 0x806ea
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8257U CPU @ 1.40GHz
 11 error-reporting banks
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200000000080005
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200000000080005
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 6, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 4395414 loops in 695999999 ticks
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff800926363c): "Machine Check at 0xffffff7f89b14d10, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007000024e7d74, CR3: 0x000000001d744000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x000000000000001a, RBX: 0xffffff802d897000, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x000000000000001b\n" "RSP: 0xffffff80fc80bc90, RBP: 0xffffff80fc80bcf0, RSI: 0xffffff802dbbfa40, RDI: 0x0000000000000000\n" "R8:  0x0000000000908000, R9:  0x0000000000008000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000001\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000001, R14: 0x0000000000000908, R15: 0xffffff802d816400\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000202, RIP: 0xffffff7f89b14d10, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.41.3/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8008f54310 : 0xffffff8009139a3b 
0xffffff8008f54360 : 0xffffff8009270fe5 
0xffffff8008f543a0 : 0xffffff8009262a5e 
0xffffff8008f543f0 : 0xffffff80090e0a40 
0xffffff8008f54410 : 0xffffff8009139127 
0xffffff8008f54510 : 0xffffff800913950b 
0xffffff8008f54560 : 0xffffff80098d17f9 
0xffffff8008f545d0 : 0xffffff800926363c 
0xffffff8008f546c0 : 0xffffff80098d1978 
0xffffff8008f546d0 : 0xffffff80090e129f 
0xffffff80fc80bcf0 : 0xffffff7f89b15002 
0xffffff80fc80bd00 : 0xffffff80098505f0 
0xffffff80fc80bd60 : 0xffffff7f89d865e6 
0xffffff80fc80bda0 : 0xffffff7f89d7a958 
0xffffff80fc80be00 : 0xffffff7f8b94753d 
0xffffff80fc80be50 : 0xffffff7f8b956aa9 
0xffffff80fc80beb0 : 0xffffff7f8b955404 
0xffffff80fc80bee0 : 0xffffff80098401bd 
0xffffff80fc80bf30 : 0xffffff800983eb02 
0xffffff80fc80bf70 : 0xffffff800983e08c 
0xffffff80fc80bfa0 : 0xffffff80090e013e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f89b10000->0xffffff7f89b46fff
         com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[A9967DFD-FCB3-3536-B071-F8B46494895B]@0xffffff7f89d77000->0xffffff7f89d9efff
         com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[B8EE9C14-90EE-39E2-8565-0B00AC09499B]@0xffffff7f8b941000->0xffffff7f8b983fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[180FC5AB-0E47-35BC-91DF-609EBE8ED4A5]@0xffffff7f8a118000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[AA7C7A4F-9F5D-3533-9E78-177C3B6A72BF]@0xffffff7f89b10000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)[A86937B2-6177-3699-BE65-6762DDC120C6]@0xffffff7f8b8e0000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[A9967DFD-FCB3-3536-B071-F8B46494895B]@0xffffff7f89d77000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[2CCA7DD3-C33F-3CA4-A213-BC83D3D997B0]@0xffffff7f89a49000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8008f00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,4 (Mac-53FDB3D8DB8CA971)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 358894448444
last loaded kext at 242751772774: @filesystems.msdosfs  1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f8d1ea000, size 69632)
last unloaded kext at 191663857295: >!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f89b55000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5430
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.9
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.9
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.1f1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.2.5
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.2
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ABacklight    180.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.55
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.55
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.422
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3410.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.2
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.41.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!A!BModule 1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!UAudio    320.49
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.9
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.9
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IONDRVSupport  568
>!AActuatorDriver   3410.2
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHS!BDriver   3410.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.1f1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3410.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3410.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.9
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.7
|IOGraphics!F   568
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.0
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.6
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.1f1
>!A!BDebug  1
>!AConvergedIPCOLYBTControl 1
>!A!BDebugService   1
>!AConvergedPCI 1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AMultiFunctionManager 1
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.41.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.1f1
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.1f1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: Do you have chrome ?

Comment: @ankii No, I do not have Chrome installed.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372183/catalina-crashing-at-shutdown-with-this-error/374003#374003 This question had `com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)` as the problem. I see `com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)` in yours. Could you try what all answers and comments suggest there, but for NVRAM ? you don't seem to have tried Safe boot

Comment: @ankii Thank you for the pointer. I forgot to mention that I was also going into safe boot (edited into original post). Regarding SMC & NVRAM - I was resetting this after each clean install. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: what is the model of your Macbook?

Comment: @Udhy my model is the MacBook Pro (13-inch Mid 2019)

Comment: I suspect it might be hardware related problem, probably memory, so run Apple Diagnostics to check the hardware.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: @Udhy Thank you for this. Unfortunately it came back without result.

Comment: sorry to hear. I always suggest to format in such cases, but you have already done it several times. Have you try to plug out all your external hardware (keyboard, headset, mouse) connected to your MBP if it persists.

Comment: @Udhy Yeah, it is quite the bother. No, I do not have anything connected to my MBP. No external devices whatsoever.