# Macbook restarts because of kernel panic restarts every 2-3 mins

Tags: kernel-panic

My 2014 mac book pro keeps restarting. After doing a google search I found a few solutions which didn't help. I  am attaching the error report , if anyone can understand the root cause please let me know.

i tried solutions found on google like booting it in safe mode and trying to recognize the problem

Also uninstalled 3rd party apps and extra peripharels but still it keeps restarting

Also alot of people say that this could be a logic board issue but i want to try all the possible software related issues before i go for the big picture

anic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801fe469aa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7fa33e1b50, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000010559e000, CR3: 0x0000000022c12000, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff803f64ea40, RCX: 0xffffff802060e0c0, RDX: 0xffffff81fcbe6000
RSP: 0xffffff820b513e90, RBP: 0xffffff820b513ea0, RSI: 0xffffff803f64ea40, RDI: 0x00ff000000000000
R8:  0xffff9fffffffffff, R9:  0x0000600000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0xffffff80207f5280
R12: 0xffffff803f64ea90, R13: 0x000002208d244125, R14: 0xffffff801fd3f920, R15: 0xffffff803f312000
RFL: 0x0000000000010086, RIP: 0xffffff7fa33e1b50, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x000000010559e000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801fb52220 : 0xffffff801fd1a65d
0xffffff801fb52270 : 0xffffff801fe54a75
0xffffff801fb522b0 : 0xffffff801fe465fe
0xffffff801fb52300 : 0xffffff801fcc0a40
0xffffff801fb52320 : 0xffffff801fd19d27
0xffffff801fb52420 : 0xffffff801fd1a117
0xffffff801fb52470 : 0xffffff80204c1a6c
0xffffff801fb524e0 : 0xffffff801fe469aa
0xffffff801fb52660 : 0xffffff801fe466a8
0xffffff801fb526b0 : 0xffffff801fcc0a40
0xffffff801fb526d0 : 0xffffff7fa33e1b50
0xffffff820b513ea0 : 0xffffff801fe41848
0xffffff820b513ed0 : 0xffffff801fd3c4d1
0xffffff820b513f40 : 0xffffff801fd3e115
0xffffff820b513f80 : 0xffffff801fd3f99b
0xffffff820b513fa0 : 0xffffff801fcc013e
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
com.apple.driver.AppleHV(1.0)[25F55CE1-4585-36A1-9EDE-2F182F9C6A19]@0xffffff7fa33de000->0xffffff7fa33e7fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H2

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 05D51A3D-3A87-3FF0-98C3-9CF3827A3EDD
Kernel slide:     0x000000001fa00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801fc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801fb00000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 2338833455358
last loaded kext at 771033184537: >!AXsanScheme 3 (addr 0xffffff7fa2278000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 1666996525105: >DiskImages.KernelBacked   493.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa3441000, size 73728)
loaded kexts:

> AudioAUUC  1.70
> @fileutil   20.036.15
> !AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
> @AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
> !AHV   1
> |IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
> |IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
> !AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
> AGPM   111.4.4
> !APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
> X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
> pmtelemetry    1
> !A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.7
> @Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
> !AHDA  283.15
> eficheck   1
> !ABacklight    180.3
> !AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
> !ASMCLMU   212
> !ALPC  3.1
> AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
> !ACameraInterface  7.6.0
> !A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.7
> !A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
> !AMCCSControl  1.14
> @filesystems.autofs 3.0
> !UCardReader   489.120.1
> !UTCKeyboard   255
> !UTCButtons    255
> !AVirtIO   1.0
> @filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
> @BootCache  40
> @!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
> @filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
> !AAHCIPort 341.140.1
> @private.KextAudit  1.0
> !ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
> !ARTC  2.0
> !AACPIButtons  6.1
> !AHPET 1.8
> !ASMBIOS   2.1
> !AACPIEC   6.1
> !AAPIC 1.7
> $!AImage4   1
> @nke.applicationfirewall    303
> $TMSafetyNet    8
> @!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
> |EndpointSecurity   1
> !AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
> |IOAVB!F    850.1
> @plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
> |IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
> DspFuncLib 283.15
> @kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
> @!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
> !ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
> |IONDRVSupport  576.1
> !AHDA!C    283.15
> |IOHDA!F    283.15
> |IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
> mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
> corecapture    1.0.4
> |IOSkywalk!F    1
> @!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
> |IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
> X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
> IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
> |IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
> !ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
> |IOGraphics!F   576.1
> @kext.triggers  1.0
> |Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f7
> |IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f7
> |IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
> |IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
> |IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
> usb.!UHub  1.2
> !UMultitouch   264
> usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
> usb.networking 5.0.0
> usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
> |IOAudio!F  300.2
> @vecLib.kext    1.2.0
> |IOSerial!F 11
> |IOSurface  269.11
> @filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
> |IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
> |IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
> !AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
> !AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
> !AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
> !AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
> |IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
> usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
> usb.!UXHCI 1.2
> |IOUSB!F    900.4.2
> !AEFINVRAM 2.1
> !AEFIRuntime   2.1
> |IOSMBus!F  1.1
> |IOHID!F    2.0.0
> $quarantine 4
> $sandbox    300.0
> @kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
> DiskImages 493.0.0
> !AFDEKeyStore  28.30
> !AEffaceable!S 1.0
> !ASSE  1.0
> !AKeyStore 2
> !UTDM  489.120.1
> |IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
> !ACredentialManager    1.0
> KernelRelayHost    1
> !ASEPManager   1.0.1
> IOSlaveProcessor   1
> |IOTimeSync!F   840.3
> |IONetworking!F 3.4
> |IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
> |IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
> |IO!S!F 2.1
> |IOUSBHost!F    1.2
> !UHostMergeProperties  1.2
> usb.!UCommon   1.0
> !ABusPower!C   1.0
> |CoreAnalytics!F    1
> !AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
> @kext.CoreTrust 1
> |IOReport!F 47
> !AACPIPlatform 6.1
> !ASMC  3.1.9
> watchdog   1
> |IOPCI!F    2.9
> |IOACPI!F   1.4
> @kec.pthread    1
> @kec.Libm   1
> @kec.corecrypto 1.0

Comment: Does it panic after you do a clean reinstall or follow Apple’s guidance - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553. For this to be open here, we would need a clearer question on what you did.

Comment: Yes i have cleaned the hard disk and installed the OS again but it was of no use

Comment: It can be time consuming to isolate, [here is my best advice](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407387/5472) if you don’t want to pay someone else to do the work or work with Apple support to narrow down / repair your gear if that’s the eventual cause.

Comment: I tried to do the advice you suggested, I am only left on trying to change or clean the RAM. If that doesn't work I will have to change the computer

Answer (score 1):

This type of kernel panic is most often caused by a defective RAM module.

The kernel panic is caused by a "general protection fault" in kernel mode. This means that the kernel (the core of the operating system) tried to access memory addresses that aren't mapped to physical RAM.

The cause of this is an invalid pointer. A pointer is basically a number stored in RAM that works as an address and "points to" a different piece of the system memory.

Invalid pointers can be caused by software bugs. However, a bug that causes a kernel panic every 2-3 minutes no matter the activity would almost certainly have been discovered by other users. Those type of software bugs that cause kernel panics are usually triggered by a specific action (such as inserting an external peripheral), and not something just happening randomly.

If you have third party kernel extensions installed - disable them to test if they have any part in the kernel panic. It is also a good idea to boot up in Recovery Mode and confirm that the kernel panics also happen here, in order to rule out third party software as a cause.

Invalid pointers can also be caused by defective RAM. This I think is the most common cause for invalid pointers happening "randomly" in kernel space with a production kernel.

There are also other, less common, causes of invalid pointers, such as for example a defective CPU, a damaged memory bus, and defective PCIe DMA units.