# How to delete kexts in Catalina?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a 2014 MacBook Pro experiencing [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/290714/macbook-pro-black-screens-and-shuts-off-after-a-few-minutes-use). Catalina does not allow kexts to be deleted via this method. Unless I am able to delete or disable this kext my laptop will shut down randomly. Anyone know how to remove kexts in Catalina?

Comment: Are you trying to modify system kernel extensions so this needs to involve system integrity protection as well as the read only system volume or just removing third party extensions?

Comment: I need to remove the AppleThunderboltNHI.kext because it causes constant crashing of my laptop.

Comment: Aah - so you’re disabling parts of the system to work around failing / failed hardware. You might edit this to put the full path to that if you want more answers. If you’re good, no need to edit of course.

Comment: @bmike: The issue is not failing hardware, it's well-known MacOS breakage since 10.12 with AppleThunderboltNHI.kext on 2014 MBP, which Apple have refused to fix for several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Terminal, enter `sudo mount -rw /`. Then run either of the commands:

1. to rename - `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Extensions ; mv -v AppleThunderboltNHI.kext AppleThunderboltNHI.kext.original`
2. `sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext`
3. `sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext`

Thanks to @Udhy and @user3439894 for the tips that led me to the answer. I also found out how to mount and change drive permissions [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/Lightroom/quot-Macintosh-HD-quot-is-Read-Only-MacOS-Catalina-10-15/td-p/10512630).

Comment: When booted to **macOS Recovery** the **Macintosh HD** is not protected and **you do not need to disable SIP!** Simple boot to **macOS Recovery**, open **Terminal** from the **Utilities** menu and use the following _command_: `rm -r /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext`  -- It's gone! Reboot... Done! That said, I would have just renamed it, e.g. : `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/System/Library/Extensions ; mv -v AppleThunderboltNHI.kext AppleThunderboltNHI.kext.original` That way, then if need be it can easily be renamed back to `AppleThunderboltNHI.kext`.

Comment: The rigamarole of rebooting to macOS Recovery, disabling SIP, rebooting back to normal mode, doing something (that actually  can be done the first time booted to macOS Recovery without disabling SIP), rebooting again the macOS Recovery, enabling SIP, rebooting again back to normal mode it a totally needless dance and a utter waste of time!

Comment: @user3439894 you should've posted that as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 11):

## 1. Check for System Integrity Protection (SIP)

Open `Terminal` and type

```bsh
csrutil status
```

if it says

```bsh
System Integrity Protection status: enabled.
```

continue to step 2. Else, skip to step 3.

## 2. Defeat SIP by [Rebooting into macOS Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

1. Turn off Mac; turn back on while hodling <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Open Terminal from the Utilities menu.
3. Type `csrutil disable`
4. Reboot (`reboot`)

## 3. Unload, then delete `kext`

In `Terminal`,

1. Unload Extension

```bsh
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
```

2. Delete Extension

```bsh
sudo mount -rw / # mount root as RW
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
```

## 4. Re-enable SIP (if turned off)

Follow the steps for 2. except type `csrutil enable` on step 2.3.

Comment: This answer worked for me. SIP was preventing me. My kext was not showing up in the directory listing in recovery mode, so I couldn't rm it from there. This is a great answer.

Answer (score 8):

**For Mac OS Big Sur**

1. Reboot in rescue mode (reboot while "Cmd + R")
2. Utilities -> Terminal
3. csrutil disable
4. csrutil authenticated-root disable
5. mount -uw /Volumes/[MacOS ]
6. delete (or rename, or move elsewhere) the AppleThunderboltNHI.kext directory (I've moved all thunderbolt kext directories since I have no needs about this interface, but I think it works only by disabling AppleThunderboltNHI)

> cd /Volumes/Macos (Enter WHATEVER YOUR MACOS DRIVE NAME IS, my macOS
> drive name is Macos)/System/Library/Extensions

> rm -rf AppleThunderboltNHI.kext

7. Remove cache

> rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*

9. REBUILD the extensions cache ! (new has-to-do in Big Sur...)

> kmutil install -u --force --volume-root /Volumes/[MacOS ]

7. DON'T FORGET to create another system snapshot to take these modifications under account at next reboot

> bless --folder /Volumes/[MacOS ]/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot

8. reboot (in rescue mode). This step may be unnecessary, not tested straight to
9. csrutil enable
10. Reboot

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and see if it works!

Comment: Had to reference my root volume as '/Volumes/[Mac OS]\ 1' for some reason. It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately csrutil authenticated-root disable doesn’t work with FileVault enabled… Will have to disable it somehow maybe in the safe mode. And you cannot enable SSV again once you’ve disabled it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal and enter the following command:

   ```
   sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
   ```
2. If that fails to work, you can also just force-delete the kext using

   Use the following Terminal command to remove the kext file:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
   ```
3. Restart your MAC

Comment: RE: 2, i.e, `sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/AppleThunderboltNHI.kext`. By default, all this will do is return the error "**Operation not permitted**" Because in macOS Catalina, by default and aside from any SIP restrictions, the e.g. Macintosh HD is mounted at `/` as `read-only` and nothing can be modified on this volume unless one boots to macOS Recovery and then either makes modifications from there, or disables SIP and then reboot and mount `/` as `rw`.

Comment: @user3439894 I tried to mount and perform these actions in Recovery and with SIP disabled. I was still unable to delete the kext.

Comment: @user3439894 so how did an app install its kext there?

Comment: @theonlygusti In **macOS Catalina**, files in `/System/Library/Extensions/` are part of the **Core.pkg** in `Install macOS Catalina.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg` and put there by Apple on a, by default, read-only filesystem (when booted normally).