# Cannot delete Karabiner Kext

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I followed the answers in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372684/how-to-delete-kexts-in-catalina) but cannot delete the kernel extension for the key mapper software Karabiner.

When I boot into recovery mode and rm -rf the enclosing folder it is not deleted when I log back in.

Also, can anyone give any knowledge on the safety of the software itself?

Any help appreciated.

- Edit - I was able to delete the extension by Booting into Mojave on the same HD.

Comment: Did you try https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document_v10.html#uninstall ?

Comment: Yes that was the first thing I did. It deletes the two apps in /Applications (which also couldn't be deleted normally) but left many files and the kext on my system. I'm really not comfortable leaving it there considering the function of the software.

Comment: Link is now broken.