# How to delete a system .kext in Monterey?

Tags: microphone, apple-silicon, kernel-extensions

I have a 2021 MacBook Pro (M1) running Monterey and I want to completely disable the built-in mic. Removing the IOAudioFamily.kext did the trick in old macOS versions (e.g. Mojave), but removing a system kext is proving to be difficult in Monterey.

I've tried:

Option #1:

- Go into Recovery Mode;
- Disable SIPS;
- Go to /System/Library/Extensions;
- `rm IOAudioFamily.kext`

... but it does not allow the removal

Option #2:
(based on [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372684/how-to-delete-kexts-in-catalina))

- Reboot in rescue mode
- `csrutil disable`
- `csrutil authenticated-root disable`
- `mount -uw /Volumes/MacintoshHD`
- `cd /Volumes/MacintoshHD/System/Library/Extensions`
- `rm -rf rm IOAudioFamily.kext`
- `rm -rf /System/Library/Caches/*`
- `kmutil install -u --force --volume-root /Volumes/MacintoshHD`
- `bless --folder /Volumes/[MacOS ]/System/Library/CoreServices --bootefi --create-snapshot`
  (This step fails: the `bless --folder` option is only available for external disks in Apple Silicon Computers)

Any idea on how to get this done?

Comment: Is you question really "how to delete a system kext" (I suspect you can't), or it is "how to disable the microphone"?

Comment: The question is how to delete a system kext. But I definitely need to completely disable the built-in microphone so it can't be turned on again. Removing the right kext should do the trick (until until one upgrades macOS) but if you have another suggestion I would really like to hear it. Thx

Comment: a different direction, but you can disconnect the mic flex cable inside the MacBook, and tape it over with some kapton. there's not a lot of slack in the cables inside the M1, so it should stay in place.